# What PayPal API Credentials I should use to go live?

Tags: meteor, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I am using PayPal Express Checkout in my project and I am using my Sandbox testing account to test the PayPal in the development environment.

I am using my `Business` account I get [from PayPal website](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/). Now I want to go live,

what should I do before I go live?

Some said that I should **ONLY** remove `sandbox` from my PayPal links, it didn't seem to work with me.

Others said that I have to create an app, but then they will give me client-ID and Secret.

Where should I place them?

because sandbox testing accounts gives me three API credentials `USER, PWD, & SIGNATURE`

from where I can get my live credentials for `USER, PWD, & SIGNATURE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to this URL with your live PayPal account:  https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run

It will drop you directly into the page that displays your username, password, and signature (with little "show" links for each one).

[image]

The long way to get there is to login to www.paypal.com, click into your profile, and look for "API Access".